# Alternative Find/Replace Method (str_replace and gsub not working)

Tags: r, string

I have a column in a data frame `clean.data$Country`. One of the cells in that is currently written as `USA(For Country)`. This is row 3216, so the observation can be viewed with `clean.data$Country[3216]`.

I am trying to insert a space between "USA" and the parenthesis, but neither of the following methods have worked:

```
clean.data$Country <- str_replace(clean.data$Country, "USA(For Territories)", "USA (For Territories)")
clean.data$Country <- gsub("USA(For Territories)", "USA (Territories)", clean.data$Country)
```

What alternative methods are there for me to do this? I have tried closing my .rmd file, clearing my workspace of all objects, and restarting RStudio.

Comment: Add `fixed = TRUE` to your `gsub` or escape your brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain of this single data point error only, just make an assignment:

```r
clean.data$Country[3216] <- "USA (For Territories)"
```

If you want a more general solution, which could fix this problem in multiple places, then use a regex pattern which does that:

```r
clean.data$Country <- sub("^(\\w+)\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1 (\\2)", clean.data$Country)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `fixed = TRUE` or escape your parentheses:

```
x <- "USA(For Territories)"

## Your attempt
gsub("USA(For Territories)", "USA (Territories)", x)
# [1] "USA(For Territories)"

## fixed = TRUE
gsub("USA(For Territories)", "USA (Territories)", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "USA (Territories)"

## Escaping the parentheses
gsub("USA\\(For Territories\\)", "USA (Territories)", x)
# [1] "USA (Territories)"
```

---

Using `str_replace`, you can try:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(x, "USA\\(For Territories\\)", "USA (Territories)")
# [1] "USA (Territories)"

str_replace(x, fixed("USA(For Territories)"), "USA (Territories)")
# [1] "USA (Territories)"
```